# GTK: Treeview with comboboxes - How to get different selectable items for each row?

Tags: c, linux, gtk, gtk3

I have prepared a simple GUI with a treeview which contains comboboxes. This works fine, I can use the comboboxes and select the specified items. However currently I can only specify the items and they are the same for the whole column, but how to get different selectable items for each row?

This is what I have now, it creates a new column with a combobox containing selectable items "item1", "item2", "item3":

```
    GtkCellRenderer *renderer;
    GtkListStore *combo_list;
    GtkTreeViewColumn *column;

    renderer = gtk_cell_renderer_combo_new ();
    combo_list = gtk_list_store_new(1, G_TYPE_STRING);

    gtk_list_store_insert_with_values(combo_list, NULL, -1, 0, "item1", -1);
    gtk_list_store_insert_with_values(combo_list, NULL, -1, 0, "item2", -1);
    gtk_list_store_insert_with_values(combo_list, NULL, -1, 0, "item3", -1);

    g_object_set(renderer, "model", combo_list, "text-column", 0, "has-entry", FALSE, "editable", TRUE, (char *)NULL); 
    column = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes("data", renderer, "text", ELEMENT_TYPEDATA, NULL);

    gtk_tree_view_append_column(GTK_TREE_VIEW(treeview), column);
```

Can anyone provide an example for that in C?